# Show/hide content on hover/click

Tags: jquery, hover, click, show-hide

Trying to show/hide content on hover of image. This is working ok, but would like the content under the first image to show by default. How can I achieve this?

https://jsfiddle.net/nsn3bpep/2/

```
    var divContent = $("#content").html();
    $("td").click(function () {
    $("#content").html($(this).find("#hover-content").html());
    $("td").removeClass('myClickState');
    $(this).addClass('myClickState');
    $(this).off('mouseleave');
   });
    $("td").hover(function () {
    $("#content").html($(this).find("#hover-content").html());
    }, function () {
    $("#content").html(divContent);
});
```

Comment: It is already showing under the first image?

Comment: Do you want show each content under the respective image ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you fiddle is showing content under the first image, I assume you need the content under each image. Here I have change id `hover-content` to a class.

```
$("td").hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.hover-content').show();
}, function(){
    $(this).find('.hover-content').hide();
});
```

You can see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7vyfuxe/3/) here.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line below your jquery script and you're done...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr:first-child>td:first-child>img.size-thumbnail').click()
});
```